# ng-show not working based on the AngularJs version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here i am created  custom directive for show and hide particular field  from json data , here my problem is  angular version, in low version its working (  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js), but high version its not supporting (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js)

please check the below link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/h3MrWQjopbqzYa0Y5pOT?p=preview

var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

```
app.directive('telBasictext1', ['$http', 'telngshowservice', function($http, telngshowservice) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      placeHold: '@',
      checkId: '@',
      className: '@',
      ngmaxLength: '@',
      ngminLength: '@',
      lblvalue: '@',
      textboxSize: '@',
      lblSize: '@',
      validate: '@',
      ngShow: '@',
      textboxtype: '@',
      getString: '@',
      position: '@',
      labelPosition: '@',
      textboxPosition: '@',
      canShow: '@',
      showorhide: '@',
    },
    template: '<div   id="{{ checkId }}" class="form-group" ng-show="true"  > ' +
      '<label size="lblSize"  class="col-sm-{{ labelPosition }} control-label" id="textboxchanges">   Test </label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-{{ textboxPosition }}"> <input type="{{ textboxtype }}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{ placeHold }}"  id="{{checkId}}"   class="{{className}}"  minlength="{{ ngminLength }}"  maxlength="{{ ngmaxLength }}"  size="{{ textboxSize }}"           ng-required="{{ validate }}" ></div></div>',

    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {



      var ngshow = iAttrs.canShow;
      var ngsplitValues = ngshow.split(",");
      var nglanguage = ngsplitValues[0]; // Language EN or Fr
      var nglabelName = ngsplitValues[1]; // Label Name
      var ngmoduleName = ngsplitValues[2]; // Module Name (global or local)

      telngshowservice.getdata(ngmoduleName).success(function(data) {

        scope.showorhide = data[nglabelName];
        console.log(scope.showorhide)


      })


    }
  };
}]);



app.factory('telngshowservice', ['$http', function($http) {
  var dataFactory = {};
  var lang = window.localStorage.language;
  dataFactory.getdata = function(moduleName) {

    if (moduleName == 'common') {

      return $http.get(labeli18nPath + '/translation_' + lang + '.json');
    } else {


      return $http.get('OPlayout.json');
    }
  };
  return dataFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong without having to click any links. You've pasted a wall of code, what is wrong with it, and where do you think the problem is? Stating that 'ng-show` doesn't work in some newer version of Angular is not really helpful. If it wasn't working, you wouldn't be the only person having this problem.

Comment: please check this url  http://plnkr.co/edit/h3MrWQjopbqzYa0Y5pOT?p=preview and edit  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js to  https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js

Comment: Have you done anything to narrow down what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to breaking changes in the `$parse` service in version **[1.3.0-beta.14](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-130-beta14-harmonious-cacophonies-2014-06-30)**:

> **core**: due to bdfc9c02, values 'f', '0', 'false', 'no', 'n', '[]' are
>   no longer treated as falsy. Only JavaScript falsy values are now
>   treated as falsy by the expression parser; there are six of them:
>   false, null, undefined, NaN, 0 and "".

Use booleans instead of strings:

```
{
    "pSearchPatient": false,
    "pAddressNo" : true,
    "pBuilding": true
}
```